# Webscraping and fastapi issues

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn about scraping and I found an article about making an API by scraping information from a site then using fastapi to serve it. It's a simple project but the way it was written on the blog page makes it really confusing.

I'm thinking they left stuff out but I don't know what that would be. Here's the link to the article:  https://www.scien.cx/2022/04/26/creating-a-skyrim-api-with-python-and-webscraping/

Here is the code that I'm trying to run. First I'm in a directory I named skypi. I made a file called sky-scrape.py. Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json
def getLinkData(link):
    return requests.get(link).content
factions = getLinkData("https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Factions_(Skyrim)")
data = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(factions, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('table', attrs={'class': 'wikitable'})
for wikiTable in table:
    table_body = wikiTable.find('tbody')
    rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
       cols = row.find_all('td')
       cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
       # Get rid of empty values
       data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])
       cleanData = list(filter(lambda x: x != [], data))
       skyrim_data[html] = cleanData *This doesn't work it throws errors saying skyrim_data not defined. If I just write it as

       skyrim_data= cleanData
```

then here's the biggest issue: I have another file run.py and I want to import the data from sky-scrape.py

here is that file:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from sky-scrape import skyrim_data
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
def home():
    return("""
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Skyrim API</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>API DO SKYRIM</h1>
            <h2>Rotas disponíveis:</h2>
            <ul>
                <a href="/factions"><li>/factions</li></a>
            </ul>
        </body>
    </html>
    """)

@app.get("/factions")
def factions():
    return skyrim_data["Factions"]
```

The from sky-scrape import skyrim_data doesn't work so I'm not sure what to do at this point. How do I get this script to work correctly?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a poor description of what is happening. What exactly doesn't work with the FastAPI? Does your scraper produce the data as required?

Comment: Sorry your right, So if i run the sky-scrape.py it works, however that last variable in the script is weird. in the source is says skyrim_data[HTML] = cleanData, this doesn't work it says that variable is not defined, but if I just use skyrim_data = cleanData that works. Now for the run.py I get errors for the from sky-scrape import skyrim_data line. that's where Im stuck

Comment: Well yes, you never defined variable `html` and you can't index a variable that hasn't been created yet so `skyrim_data[html]` shouldn't work

Comment: Yes, that article has code that shouldn't work. Why not just have it as `skyrim_data = cleanData`? I believe this might work.

Comment: ok so one issue was sky-scrape, the hyphen was throwing things off I changed the name to skyscraper and that error is gone. I have skyrim_data= cleanData, that does work. Now skyrun.py when I run that now it serves the page but if I click on the endpoint for the API info I get an error that says list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

Comment: Setting `skyrim_data = clean_data` doesn't look right, because it's inside a loop (actually two nested loops).  So in the end, the variable `skyrim_data` would contain only the result of the last iteration.  All the previous data will be thrown away.